# Record is not visible in footer of gridview that is inside a listview

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am using gridview inside listview on listview_itembound event im getting records as per requirement bt the prbm is this that im having footer in my gridview where i have to show some record bt data is not visible in my grid please help me by telling were im wrong follow is my code:

```
protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        ListViewDataItem item = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;
        GridView grdview = (GridView)item.FindControl("GridView1");
        Label lblenqid = (Label)item.FindControl("Label2");
        Label lblclientname = (Label)item.FindControl("Label3");
        //string enquiryid = lblenqid.Text;
        DateTime ArrivesOn = DateTime.Parse(txtstartdate.Text);
        //GridView grdvw = (GridView)ListView1.FindControl("GridView1") as GridView;
        objHotel.Tour_Detail(grdview, ArrivesOn,lblclientname.Text,lblenqid.Text);
        //objHotel.Tour_DetailVehiclePackageCost(grdview, lblenqid.Text);
    }
}

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        GridView grdview1 = (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("GridView1");
        Label lblenqid = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblenqid1");
        Label lblname = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblname");
        DateTime ArrivesOn = DateTime.Parse(txtstartdate.Text);

        objHotel.Tour_Detail(grdview1, ArrivesOn, lblname.Text, lblenqid.Text);
        //objHotel.Tour_DetailVehiclePackageCost(grdview1, lblenqid.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of data do you want to show in the footer?  There is no current row for the footer so you can't bind it to anything in the datasource.

Comment: in my design i have footer template in gridview dats why i write the code for footer

Comment: can u please tell me what i have to do should i write diff stored procedure for only footer or the code that i hv done for gridview will work for it and how i bind the data in footer template.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you're trying to add some summary on the footer, to display it you should add something like this depending on which column you need to display it:

```
e.Row.Cells[i].Text = "Total: " + GetYourValue();
```

Comment: bt im not doing any kind of calculation in footer simply want to bind footer template with values that stored in database jst dnt knw how to bind that record in footer like we bind in item template of gridview or list view